# выполнять скрипт с аргументом в случае если удольвлетворяет условия

Tags: bash

Есть скрипт который делает следуюещее:

```
./students.sh |awk '{print $1,$4}'
Serghei
Alexei [Found]
Andrei [Found]
Vladimir [FOUND]
Nataliya
#ЕСЛИ находит Alexei [Found] Andrei [Found] Vladimir [FOUND]  выполняет ->
./students.sh -move
#если не находит одного или двух из трех студентов - ничего не делает
```

Нужна ваша помощь в создании условия в которых при нахождении именно ВСЕХ этих студентов аргумент -move , применялся к этому скрипту. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это же простой скрипт для *AWK*:

```awk
{
    if ($1 == "Alexei" && $4 == "[Found]") {
        alexei = 1;
    } else if ($1 == "Andrei" && $4 == "[Found]") {
        andrei = 1;
    } else if ($1 == "Vladimir" && $4 == "[FOUND]") {
        vladimir = 1;
    }
}

END {
    if (alexei && andrei && vladimir) {
        system("./students.sh -move");
    } else {
        system("./students.sh");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, очень помогло!

Comment: есть ли  у вас кошелек - я бы скинул за помощь деньгу

Comment: Спасибо, плюсов достаточно.